# Way to write a aggregation query with a divide operation on size array in projection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'd like to run this aggregation query using Spring Data MongoDB.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(
   {
        "$group": {
        "_id": "$searchTerm",
        "dateAddToSet": {
            "$addToSet": "$date"
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
        "searchTerm": "$_id.searchTerm",
        "percent": {
            "$divide": [{ "$size": "$dateAddToSet" }, 28]
        }
    }
  })
```

I can't find way to write the divide operation on $dataAddToSet size to execute this query.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Bit of advice. It would have helped your cause if you wrote a valid statement to begin with. Only `{ "$divide": [{ "$size": "$dateAddToSet"}, 28 ] }` would be valid here. Wrapping the array would cause an error. Or at least an invalid value of `1`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This query works fine and returns me a good result. But you're right, I'll edit my query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. The main problem here is that [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) is not a supported operation in spring mongo at the moment. So the only way to get operations constructed is to use the DBObject construction.

But you can intermix the two methods by providing a wrapper class of your own, such as:

```java
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public CustomAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

So generally override the `.toDBObject()` method to just return the `DBObject` data that was supplied to the constructor of the class.

Then use later in construction of your aggregation:

```java
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group("searchTerm")
                    .addToSet("date").as("dateAddToSet"),
            new CustomAggregationOperation(
                new BasicDBObject("$project",
                    new BasicDBObject("_id",0)
                        .append("searchTerm","$_id")
                        .append("percent",new BasicDBObject(
                                "$divide", new Object[]{
                                    new BasicDBObject("$size","dateAddToSet"),
                                    28
                                }

                            )
                        )
                )
            )
    );
```

And that produces a pipeline with the correct format:

```java
{ 
    "aggregate" : "__collection__" , 
    "pipeline" : [ 
        { "$group" : { 
            "_id" : "$searchTerm" , 
            "dateAddToSet" : { "$addToSet" : "$date" }
        }}, 
        { "$project" : { 
            "_id" : 0 ,
            "searchTerm" : "$_id" , 
            "percent" : { "$divide" : [ { "$size" : "$dateAddToSet" } , 28] }
        }}
    ]
}
```

So that is one way to mix the available builders with custom construction so you can use methods where a builder does not presently exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helps me a lot. I didn't know this way to customize my aggregation query. I will implement this right now!